# Why my app logouts after 5-6 minutes though I have set max Age to 3 hours?

Tags: express, session-cookies, express-session

I have build an app using Node.js and Express.js which is running well on server but the problem is that it automatically logs out me within 5 to 6 minutes of logged in time. I think the problem is due to session and I tried keeping maxAge very large but it won't worked. Interesting thing is that when I shorten maxAge to less than 5-6 minutes, it works well as defined.

I have set session as

```
app.use(session({
    genid: function(req) {
        return uniqueString(); // use UUIDs for session IDs
    }, 
    secret: USER_SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        maxAge:  24*60*60*1000
    }
}));
```

Actually, I wanted to keep maxAge to very large so that user doesn't get interrupted in middle. What may be possible problem in this case? Is this a problem due to hosting server ?

Note: It works fine while running on localhost.

Comment: is your hosting server memory constrained?

Comment: Yes, it is shared hosting with 2GB memory and unlimited disk space.

Comment: 2GB is lot but check if your server is running out of memory and restarting? or some other process doing the restart?

Comment: No, just 7% of total memory is used yet. I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: you're using the default `MemoryStore` to store session, so it's probably got to do with how memory is managed on your cloud host

Comment: So, what can I do?

Comment: You could use db to store session, Under the section `Compatible Session Stores` you'll find db connectors https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/session.html